# Fixing code for left isosceles triangle in python and right isosceles triangle as well

Tags: python

I need to create code that produces a left isosceles triangle of asterisk but have been struggling coming up with code.

```
for i in range(number):
    print(' '*(number-i-1)+'*'*(2*i+1))
```

this is code for an downwards isosceles triangle but I have no clue on how to create code to make the isosceles triangle point to the left and if possible how to make the triangle point to the right in my code as well.

No error message just need some help editing my code or possibly creating a new one to solve my left isosceles triangle of asterisk problem in python.

Comment: Hi Paul, your code produces an isosceles triangle that points upwards which I have already solved for. I am looking for an isosceles triangle that will point left and right, help would greatly be appreciated because I am lost.

Comment: that is because it is your code. I just changed the formatting to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

You can use similar logic to what you are doing above but you have to loop twice if you don't want to get more complex since you need to count up and then down, and not just up like when you do it pointing up or down.

You could probably do a loop starting with negative numbers going to positive and vice versa but I'm not going to solve that further for you.

```py
>>> def triangle_left(number):
...     for i in range(number):
...         print(' '*(number-i-1)+'*'*(i+1))
...     for i in range(number-2,-1,-1):
...         print(' '*(number-i-1)+'*'*(i+1))
... 
>>> triangle_left(5)
    *
   **
  ***
 ****
*****
 ****
  ***
   **
    *
```

And

```py
>>> def triangle(number):
...     for i in range(number):
...         print('*'*(i+1))
...     for i in range(number):
...         print('*'*(number-i-1))
... 
>>> triangle(5)
*
**
***
****
*****
****
***
**
*
```